# Consequence of Radon measure inner regularity property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ $\mu$-measurable. The following holds: $$ \mu (A) = \text{sup} \{\mu(F): F \subset A, F \text{ compact}\}.$$

I am trying to show the following: "Assume $\mu(A) < + \infty.$ For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a compact set $F \subset A$ such that $\mu(A \setminus F) < \epsilon$."

This is what I have so far:
By definition of the supremum, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a compact set $F \subset A$ such that $\mu(F) > \mu(A) - \epsilon$. If $F$ is $\mu$-measurable, then we have by definition of measurability $$\mu(A) = \mu(A \cap F) + \mu(A \setminus F) = \mu(F) + \mu(A \setminus F). $$ Since $\mu(F) < + \infty$, we thus have $$ \mu(A \setminus F) = \mu(A) - \mu(F) < \mu(A) - (\mu(A) - \epsilon) = \epsilon. $$ How do I show the claim for $F$ not $\mu$-measurable? 
(Remark: I am reading Evans-Gariepy where the term measure is used for an outer measure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $F$ is a Borel set, since it is closed. As $\mu$ is a Radon measure, every Borel set is $\mu$-measurable. Thus $F$ is always $\mu$-measurable.